# Downloading image from stream

Tags: android

From the two lines below, in which line the actual download happens ?. and if possible please explain

```
InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imageURL).openStream();
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

Comment: It happens in first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imageURL).openStream();
```

Creates a connection to the URL. The result is a stream, that can be used to get the content of the URL.

This:

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

Uses the above mentioned stream to read the URL's content and use it to create the bitmap, so this is where the "download" happens. Bear in mind, that this doesn't mean the image is actually saved on the internal memory or SD card. It's just there in memory.

Comment: so you are saying its the second line, the download happens. it contradicts with a comment to my question

Comment: I am pretty sure no data transfer is done on the first line. A stream is just opened, no data is fetched.

Comment: is opening a stream an expensive process, the thing is i only want to download if some condition is met.

Comment: You can consider it an expensive process. You should definitely not do it if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for getting and saving .

Also you can easly work with Universal Image lOader library or picasso 
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader 
http://square.github.io/picasso/

URL url = new URL("....your site .....");

```
InputStream input = null;
FileOutputStream output = null;

try {
    String outputName =  "thumbnail.jpg";

    input = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
    output = c.openFileOutput(outputName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    int read;
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    while ((read = input.read(data)) != -1)
        output.write(data, 0, read);

    return outputName;

} finally {
    if (output != null)
        output.close();
    if (input != null)
        input.close();
}
```

Comment: i didn't ask how to download image or ways to download image